# jQuery click event firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

This is a fairly weird case, you can see the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zpZtH/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not wrap `input` elements by using a `label` element, try this:

```
<label for="average-data" class="section-view-time-checkbox">
    <span class="custom checkbox checked"></span> Average  
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="average-data" style="display: none;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zpZtH/7/

Comment: Just got rid of it all together. Don't really need it as i'm not submitting the forms. Only taking advantage of some CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cc55g/

You need to call `event.preventDefault()` within your click handler. This prevents the default click action from being executed once your custom function runs. The second alert is occurring because the form is being submitted.

Comment: Why is the form being submitted? This is just a `label`? Also, the reason I don't want to do `event.preventDefault()` is because I'm also occasionally embedding links in the label that goes to another page.

Comment: I really don't know. The default click behavior on an input element apparently changes the state of the element causing it to refresh somehow. Doesn't really matter since you know what you want it to do, you can have it avoid the other behaviors; I am curious myself though, I'll post here if I come across a good explanation

Comment: You can bind a different click listener to the anchor links and call `event.stopPropagation()` in that listener to prevent the click from being triggered on its parent elements. Then it will do its default redirect/changehash action and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Bug in Javascript. you can find many articles around internet specially on SO for event being fired twice. You can try something like this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#task-list li', function(e)
 {
       alert('Hellow world');
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
 });
```

And it's definitely Javascript problem because if you hit google and search for **event fire twice** you will see that Angular, Jquery and backbone etc all are somewhere firing events twice or even thrice. So, it's seems that it's javascript behind this. And off course if you search this with Mozilla Developers Network then you can see experts have also said so.